# Understanding the logic behind JS Event and handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Below is a JS/Html code that I wrote to validate the first name and last name. When the field left blank, it will show red color and when the field hasn't left blank, it will show green color.

Now, can someone please help me understand the logic behind this line of code?

```
var control = document.getElementById(controlID);
```

Here is the full program...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function validateRequiredFields(controlID) {
            var control = document.getElementById(controlID);  //Why are we assigning this to a variable ? what is happening at this code. 
            control.style.color = 'white';

            if (control.value == "") {
                control.style.background = 'red';
            } else {
                control.style.background = 'green';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> Below is the First Name and Last Name Validation Example. </br>
        1. When the field is blank, it will show red color.</br>
        2. When the field is not blank, it wil show green color.</br>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" onkeyup="validateRequiredFields('txtFirstName')"
                    onblur="validateRequiredFields('txtFirstName')">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtLastName" onkeyup="validateRequiredFields('txtLastName')"
                    onblur="validateRequiredFields('txtLastName')">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's just finding the node and re-using it instead of looking it up multiple times. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Check out the docs! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: @VLAZ - it's executing correctly, but I'm getting started with JS and trying to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: There is no "logic", it's just basic programming instructions. `document.getElementById(controlID)` will (as the name already states) find an element with a given ID. That element is then saved as a variable called `control`.

Answer (score 0):

basically your are accessing the DOM node with the ID passed **controlID**, once you have a reference to it you can play with it, in this case tweaking the style

```
<input id="someId" .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

In doing `var control = document.getElementById(controlID);` You are sending the ID of the DOM node to function and  fetching the reference of DOM node and reading it into another variable so that you need not call `document.getElementById(controlID)`; multiple times as it is expensive operation –

Answer (score 0):

> Why are we assigning this to a variable ? what is happening at this code.

`control` is used **four** times after the value is assigned to it.

If you didn't assign the return value of `document.getElementById(controlID)` to `control` then:

- The code would be longer and less readable
- The function would have to be called multiple times (which is less efficient, although not hugely so in this particular situation)

Answer (score 0):

As per your questions 
Why are we assigning this to a variable ?

**As to avoid writing same piece of code multiple time.**

what is happening at this code.

**This is saving a reference to the DOM element  
so that it can be used for dynamically updating attributes of the HTML tag on fly.**

As in your code you can see you are updating using the reference:
 control.style.background = 'red';

Answer (score 0):

"document.getElementById(controlID);"

So this is a javascript method to select something in the html (DOM), 
as the name prescribes, this is a selector which is using the ID of the html tag and searching & selecting it in the html (DOM).

Once the method finds the matching id the function returns the html element itself corresponding to the selected tag and this is stored in the variable control:

var control = document.getElementById(controlID);

Now the variable control has that element and we can call the methods to update and modify the element from our javascript and hence manipulate html through javascript program,
 here we are checking and coloring the background of the selected textbox which is determined by the method call, as it is called from both the textboxes but with different arguments, the textbox which calls it changes color.

Hope that helps!